# Totally confused what the Kernel is

Tags: abstract-algebra

Compute $\ker(\phi)$ for $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_7$ such that $\phi(1)=4$

My answer say that[image]

I have no idea what they mean by "4 has order 7 in $\mathbb{Z}_7$"

All I can write is that $\ker(\phi) = \{ m \in \mathbb{Z} : \phi(m) =0\}$ because $0$ is the identity in $\mathbb{Z_7}$ right? But I donn't know what $\phi$ is, so I don't know how to continue. And I have no idea why theya re breaking up the sum inside $\phi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, and you know that $\varphi(1)=4$. Therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\varphi(2)&=\varphi(1+1)=\varphi(1)+_7\varphi(1)=4+_74=1\\
\varphi(3)&=\varphi(2+1)=\varphi(2)+_7\varphi(1)=1+_74=5\\
\varphi(4)&=\varphi(3+1)=\varphi(3)+_7\varphi(1)=5+_74=2\\
\varphi(5)&=\varphi(4+1)=\varphi(4)+_7\varphi(1)=2+_74=6\\
\varphi(6)&=\varphi(5+1)=\varphi(5)+_7\varphi(1)=6+_74=3\\
\varphi(7)&=\varphi(6+1)=\varphi(6)+_7\varphi(1)=3+_74=0\;,\text{ and}\\
\varphi(8)&=\varphi(7+1)=\varphi(7)+_7\varphi(1)=0+_74=4\;.
\end{align*}$$

Here I’m using the homomorphism property: $\varphi(m+n)=\varphi(m)+_7\varphi(n)$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb Z$.

Clearly the values of $\varphi(n)$ will cycle through the pattern $4,1,5,2,6,3,0$ repeatedly. The length of the cycle is $7$, so every seventh value of $\varphi(n)$ will be $0$, starting with $\varphi(7)$; from that it’s not hard to see that

$$\ker\varphi=\{n\in\Bbb Z:\varphi(n)=0\}=\{n\in\Bbb Z:7\mid n\}=7\Bbb Z\;,$$

the set of multiples of $7$.

To say that $4$ has order $7$ in $\Bbb Z_7$ just means that the smallest positive integer $n$ such that
$$\underbrace{4+_7\ldots+_74}_n=0\text{ in }Z_7$$ is $n=7$. We saw this in the chart above: starting with $4$ and repeatedly adding $4$ produced in turn $4,1,5,2,6,3,0$, the cycle that we already noted, and it wasn’t until we’d added together seven $4$’s that we got the additive identity $0$ of $\Bbb Z_7$.

They were using the fact that $\varphi$ is homomorphism when they calculated $\varphi(25)$. First, $25=21+4$, so by the homomorphorphism property $\varphi(25)=\varphi(21)+_7\varphi(4)$. Now $21$ is a multiple of $7$, so $21\in\ker\varphi$, and $\varphi(21)=0$, and therefore $\varphi(25)=0+_7\varphi(4)=\varphi(4)$. Then they split $4$ as $1+1+1+1$ and used the homomorphism property again:

$$\begin{align*}
\varphi(4)&=\varphi(1)+_7\varphi(1)+_7\varphi(1)+_7\varphi(1)\\
&=4+_74+_74+_74\\
&=(4+_74)+_7(4+_74)\\
&=1+_71\\
&=2\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: so how did they know the order so quickly without doing the brute force? I mean even $\underbrace{4+_7\ldots+_74}_n=0\text{ in }Z_7$ for me takes a while to compute

Comment: @sizz: Because $7$ is prime, so every every non-zero element of $\Bbb Z_7$ has order $7$. Lagrange’s theorem: the order of an element must divide the order of the group. The only divisors of $7$ are $1$ and $7$, so every element that isn’t the identity must have order $7$.

Comment: If I were to tweak the problem a little. What would happen if we were to map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z_8}$?. The divisors are 4 and 2. After working out the algebra, it turns out the order of $4$ is $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_8$. So by Lagrange's theorem, Is it just |8|/|4| = 2? Also I thought Lagrange Theorem say that the order of a *subgroup* must divide the order of the group, why do you say 'element'?

Comment: I also have another example where $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z_10}$ where $\phi(1) = 6$ and the book again says it is $5$. I had to work out the brute force method to verify and using Lagrange's theorem too I got 2 and 5 as my divisor for 10. But I didn't know which to pick

Comment: @sizz: (1) If $\varphi:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_8$ and $\varphi(1)=4$, then $\ker\varphi=2\Bbb Z$: $\varphi$ takes every even integer to $0$ in $\Bbb Z_8$. (2) The order of an element $x$ of a group $G$ is equal to the order of the subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ of $G$ generated by $x$, so Lagrange’s theorem does give the result that I stated. (3) In $\Bbb Z_{10}$ the elements of order $5$ are the multiples of $2$, $5$ is the only element of order $2$, and the other odd numbers have order $10$. In $\Bbb Z_n$ the order of an element $k$ is $\dfrac{n}{\gcd(k,n)}$.

Comment: (1) How do you know that $\phi$ has this property without computing first? (3) *the elements of order $5$ are the multiples of $2$* how do you know this?

Comment: @sizz: (1) It was immediately obvious to me that $4+_84=0$, which is enough to tell me that $\varphi(n)$ is going to alternate between $4$ and $0$, with value $0$ when $n$ is even. (3) Because I know the result in the last sentence of my previous comment. But in this case it’s even easier: if $k$ is even, then $5k$ is a multiple of $10$ and therefore is $0$ in $\Bbb Z_{10}$, so the order of any even number in $\Bbb Z_{10}$ must be a divisor of $5$. If the even number isn’t $0$, its order can’t be $1$, so it must be $5$.

Comment: What if you have more divisors? Giving another example now, what if  $\mathbb{Z}_{10} \to \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ where $\phi(1) = 8$? The divisors of 20 are 5,4, 10, and 2. How do I immediately know the order of '8' is 5 in $\mathbb{Z_{20}}$ here? I used the same algorithm you did, that is 8k = .... and I found that I got 5 to be the cycle. Is that the "normal" method?

Comment: @sizz: From the formula that I gave: $$\frac{20}{\gcd(8,20)}=\frac{20}4=5\;.$$ Of course at some point you have to prove this formula. But what you did is fine: the smallest positive integer $p$ such that $n\mid pk$ is the order of $k$ in $\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: So my book secretly used that formula without telling me? It actually resembles Lagrange's Theorem a lot

Comment: I have another similar example (not with just integers this time) that i want to add and would like your insight. Should I ask and edit here or just make a new question?

Comment: @sizz: At this point you’d probably better make it a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for sure $\,7\Bbb Z\subset \ker\phi\,$ , right? Because

$$\phi(7k):=7k\phi(1)=28k=0\pmod 7$$

OTOH,

$$n\in\ker\phi\Longrightarrow 4n=0\pmod 7\Longrightarrow n=0\pmod 7\,\,(\text{since}\,\,(4,7)=1)\Longrightarrow$$

$$\Longrightarrow \ker\phi\subset 7\Bbb Z$$

Comment: Is there anyway to dumb it down even further for me?

Answer (score 3):

Start computing. Because $\phi(1)=4$, it follows that $\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=4+4=1$. (Remember, we are working in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.) Keep calculating. We get $\phi(3)=\phi(2+1)=1+4=5$, $\phi(4)=2$, $\phi(5)=6$, $\phi(6)=3$, and $\phi(7)=0$. Bingo!

It is now fairly easy to see that $\phi(n)=0$ precisely if $n$ is a multiple, positive or negative, of $7$. For any integer $n$ can be expressed as $n=7q+r$, where $0\le r\le 6$. So now we know the kernel of $\phi$.

Answer (score 2):

"4 has order 7" means that $$4+4+4+4+4+4+4$$ (7 times) is the identity element in $\Bbb Z_7$, and no smaller (non-trivial) sum of fours is.

For any homomorphism $\psi:G\to H$ between groups $G$ and $H$ (for notational simplicity I'm assuming they are abelian, although the exact analogus result holds for non-abelian groups) you have that
$$
\psi(a+_Gb) = \psi(a)+_H\psi(b).
$$
This means that if we know $a$ to be in the kernel of $\psi$, then $\psi(a+_G b) = 0_H +_H\psi(b) = \psi(b)$. It also means that if $G=\Bbb Z$, then $\psi$ is completely determined by the value of $\psi(1)$. In your case, $$\phi(4) = \phi(1+1+1+1) = \phi(1) +_7\phi(1) +_7\phi(1) +_7\phi(1) = 2_7.$$This ability use the homomorphism on each term in turn is the reason they break it up in your answer.